Scylla/Cassandra: Best way prevent upserts for time series workloads using TWCS
We're using Scylla but same issue with Cassandra
Doc says about TWCS:

Caution
Avoid overwriting data and deleting data explicitly at all costs, as this can potentially block an expired SSTable from being purged, due to the checks that are performed to avoid data resurrection.

Link
Data model like:
CREATE TABLE telemetry (
device_id text,
date text,
occurred_on timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY ((device_id, date), occurred_on)
)

What's the best way prevent upserts when use TWCS? I knew some ways but there are too many tradeoffs:

Use lightweight transactions - sounds good but dramaticly decreased performance for insert workloads
Use TimeUUID for occurred_on instead of timestamp to guarantee unique rows - but it's generally not recomended for this purposes (don't know why, may be that have too much overhead on convert from timeUUID to time when load data from SELECT?) Link

Maybe exists another choise and what would be the best?

Can you please clarify why with this schema will you ever have "overwriting data or deleting data explicitly"? When a certain device device_id reports an event on a certain time occured_on, how could it possibly want to modify this event later? Why would it want to delete this event later? If you're worried about a device re-sending the same update (which may look like an update), it's fine if it happens in close time proximity - and it's unlikely to happen after a long time (namely, the TWCS window size) so it's fine.

Thanks for answer! Messages from devices come from another service by message broker (kafka). So there are unreliable situations that can be: 1) Retry to send or handle a message (infrastructure or network issues) 2) Have a chance that the same event can arrive again after a hour/day/week (kafka lag with retry message and some broken services). We assume that we can loose some messages, but we don't want upsert it. Because of phrase from documentation "Avoid overwriting data at all costs" and no answer/best practice how can we work with high workloads in this case

If the retransmission happens in a time significantly shorter than the TWCS window size (e.g., one minute compared to one day), you won't have a problem because both copies will end up in the same window. You're right that if you have a one day TWCS window size and suddenly replay a week old data - this will cause a mess. However, as far as I know, even this "mess" will be limited to problems like not being able to delete expired data for another week, and things like that - I don't think there will be anything really wrong.
